# Mysql query to get only common values separated by comma from selected rows

Tags: mysql

Hello friends I have a table below having id, Roll_no & date, from below table 
  i just want repeated values which are having in all rows.

```
id -- Roll_no -- date
--------------------
1    1,2,3,4  -- 2017-09-01
2    1,2,4,5  -- 2017-09-02
3    1,2,4    -- 2017-09-03
```

I want result **1,2,4** which are common in all 3 records

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: What Strawberry said. Don't store comma separated values in a relational database.